# Php domain availability checker - Need an ajax code or similar to show result without reloading site

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-submit

I have a onepage site and I found this code for a domain checker, it works great but the problem is that when I submit the search it goes to the top of the page and I need to scroll back down to see the result. Can anyone help me so when I do the search it stays at the same place? I think ajax will do the job but I have not knowledge about it, and don't even know how to search for what I need.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Check Domain Name Availability</h3>
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-24" >
                    <input type="text" name="domain" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Example.com or Example.in etc." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>


                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
 error_reporting(0);
 if(isset($_GET['domain'])){
     $domain = $_GET['domain'];
     $godaddycheck = 'https://in.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck='.$domain.'';
     $namecomcheck = 'https://www.name.com/domain/search/'.$domain.'';
     $registercomcheck = 'http://www.register.com/domain/search/wizard.rcmx?searchDomainName='.$domain.'&searchPath=Default&searchTlds=';
 if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
  echo "<h1>Already Registered!</h1>";
 }
 else {
  echo "<h3>$domain</h3><h2><br>Not Taken, you can register it.
  </h2>";
 }
 }
?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is unlikely that CORS will be enabled ( it might be? ) on the `godaddy.com` or `name.com` websites so Ajax will not be of much use cross-origin. You could make the ajax request to a script on your site which will issue the necessary curl / http requests instead

Comment: What have you tired?, the code you have also is not actually querying them urls, its just using gethostbyname :/

Comment: It seems that `GoDaddy` at least has a developer's API which, by the looks of things, allows you to perform a domain name search - https://developer.godaddy.com/. In fact, after a brief check, all of the providers listed here offer APIs to access this type of data - though none are likely to be free